# Factoring positive real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't understand how he goes from this:

$$a=\frac{b}{\sqrt {c^2-d^2}}$$

To this:

$$a=\frac{b/c}{\sqrt {1- \frac {d^2}{c^2}}}$$ , where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$

Comment: Multiply by $c$ on top and bottom.Then on the bottom factor the $c$ into the square root.

Comment: I think you mean by $\frac{1}{c}$

Comment: @JonHerman No, I mean $c$. Note that $\dfrac c c\cdot \dfrac{\frac b c}{\sqrt {1- \frac {d^2}{c^2}}}=\dfrac{c\frac bc }{\sqrt{c^2}\sqrt{1-\frac{d^2}{c^2}}}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply multiply by $\frac 1c$ on the top and bottom.
$$\begin{align}
a &= \frac{b}{\sqrt{c^2-d^2}} \\ \\
&= \frac{b/c}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{c^2-d^2}}{c}\right)} \\ \\
&= \frac{b/c}{\sqrt{\frac{c^2-d^2}{c^2}}} \\ \\
&= \frac{b/c}{\sqrt{1-\frac{d^2}{c^2}}} \\
\end{align}$$
You just have to remember that $\frac{\sqrt a}b=\sqrt{\frac{a}{b^2}}$ (shown in the third step)

Answer (score 3):

The trick here is that $c=\sqrt{c^2}$, since $c>0$ and that $\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt x\sqrt y$

Together these allow us to write

$$\sqrt{c^2-d^2}=\sqrt{c^2\left(1-{d^2\over c^2}\right)}=c\sqrt{1-{d^2\over c^2}}$$

Then since fractions work so that

$${x\over yz}={x/y\over z}$$

we move the $c$ in the denominator up to get

$$a={b/c\over\sqrt{1-{d^2\over c^2}}}$$

so that both expressions for $a$ are equal.

Comment: @Git Gud:  thanks for fixing the wacky paren!